# Embedding JPEG in SVG using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, svg

I am wondering how to include jpg-images in SVG!

```js
var ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var svg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg');
svg.setAttribute('width', 800);
svg.setAttribute('height', 450);

var image = document.createElementNS(ns, 'image');
image.setAttribute('href', 'http://placehold.it/300x300');
image.setAttribute('x', 0);
image.setAttribute('y', 0);
image.setAttribute('width', 800);
image.setAttribute('height', 450);

svg.appendChild(image);
document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What's the issue? Works for me

Comment: do you see the image ?!

Comment: Yes, what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Safari ... :(

Comment: so it turns out safari is having trouble rendering svg images ... In chrome there is no problem. ;-( stupid safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Safari you'd need to change

```
image.setAttribute('href', 'http://placehold.it/300x300');
```

to

```
image.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'http://placehold.it/300x300');
```

This second way of doing things is Chrome/Firefox compatible too.

Safari may support your way in the future as it's part of the upcoming SVG 2 specification, the second way is the SVG 1.1 way to do things.

Comment: I also needed this fix to make it work on Firefox 50.1.0 running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Firefox 51 will be the first release to support bare href attributes. Only a few days to wait now.